# PivotItem Header and ListPicker inside

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-7, listpicker, pivotitem

I am facing an issue with `ListPicker` inside `PivotItem` header. How to resolve it?

My code:

```
<controls:PivotItem Name="PivotItemTop">
<controls:PivotItem.Header>    
    <StackPanel Background="#6DA3BD" 
                Margin="-24,-20,-1,0"
                Width="420"
                Name="StackPanelTop">  
        <TextBlock Text="TEST"
                    FontSize="48"
                    Foreground="White"
                    Padding="23,0"/>
        <toolkit:ListPicker Margin="24,0,24,10" 
                            Template="{StaticResource ListPickerTemplate}"
                            Name="ListPickerTop"
                            SelectionChanged="ListPickerTop_SelectionChanged">
        </toolkit:ListPicker>
    </StackPanel>
</controls:PivotItem.Header>

<ListBox Name="ListBoxTop"
                ItemsSource="{Binding TopItems}"
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemListBox}"/>

</controls:PivotItem>
```

and to fill:

```
ListPickerTop.ItemsSource = new List<string> { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" };
```

Please see result on picture:

[Example page.](http://www35.zippyshare.com/v/52464056/file.html)

[Image of problem http://www35.zippyshare.com/i/52464056/9126813/qqqq.png](http://www35.zippyshare.com/i/52464056/9126813/qqqq.png)

Comment: You should consider changing this to use the ApplicationBar and a fullscreen listpicker. This looks like it would be awkward to use in reality (since half of what is on the screen would be pushed down if you ever got this working)